# Firebase captcha check fails and prevents user from authenticating

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I dont have idea why this error pop up . When I run the app on other device the app goes well but when I face issue on other device . Also I have issue while I am accessing firebase via wifi . I have contacted firebase support they say in INDIA they are facing issue with server and isp

otpVerification.kt

```
const val USER_REF:String="user"
class OtpVerification : AppCompatActivity() {


lateinit var  auth: FirebaseAuth

private var mAuthVerificationId: String? = null

private var mOtpText: EditText? = null
private var mVerifyBtn: Button? = null

private var mOtpProgress: ProgressBar? = null

private var mOtpFeedback: TextView? = null

lateinit var email:String
lateinit var password: String

private lateinit var database: DatabaseReference

lateinit  var uname:String


lateinit  var mCurrentUser: FirebaseUser
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp_verification)


    mAuthVerificationId = intent.getStringExtra("AuthCredentials")
    Log.d("AuthCredentials", mAuthVerificationId.toString())

    email= intent.getStringExtra("email").toString()
    password= intent.getStringExtra("password").toString()
    uname= intent.getStringExtra("name").toString()

    mOtpFeedback = findViewById(R.id.otp_form_feedback)
    mOtpProgress = findViewById(R.id.otp_progress_bar)
    mOtpText = findViewById(R.id.otp_text_view)


    auth=Firebase.auth

    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference


    mVerifyBtn = findViewById(R.id.verify_btn)

    mVerifyBtn?.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
        val otp = mOtpText?.text.toString()
        if (otp.isEmpty()) {
            mOtpFeedback?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mOtpFeedback?.text = "Please fill in the form and try again."
        } else {
            mOtpProgress?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            mVerifyBtn?.isEnabled = false
            val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mAuthVerificationId!!, otp)
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential)
        }
    })
  }

  private fun signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential) {
    auth?.signInWithCredential(credential)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener(this,
                    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult?> { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {

                            createAccount(email,password)
                            mCurrentUser= auth.currentUser!!
                            Prefs.put(this, mCurrentUser)
                            Log.d("user",mCurrentUser.toString())
                            sendUserToHome()
                            Log.d("TAG", "Task is succesful")
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            if (task.exception is FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                                // The verification code entered was invalid
                                mOtpFeedback?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                                mOtpFeedback?.text = "There was an error verifying OTP"
                            }
                        }
                        mOtpProgress?.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                        mVerifyBtn?.isEnabled = true
                    })
 }


 fun sendUserToHome() {
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()
}

private fun createAccount(email: String, password: String) {
    Log.d("TAG", "createAccount:${email.toString()}")
    //Log.d("TAG", "validate form is ${validateForm().toString()}")

    // [START create_user_with_email]
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:success")
                    val user = auth.currentUser

                    Toast.makeText(baseContext, "Authentication Success $user", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show()
                    sendEmailVerification()

                    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    startActivity(intent)
                    Log.d("Delete", "deleting activity signup")

                    finish()

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w("TAG", "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(
                            baseContext, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                    //                   updateUI(null)
                }

                // [START_EXCLUDE]

                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
    // [END create_user_with_email]
createUSer()
}

private fun sendEmailVerification() {
           // Send verification email
    // [START send_email_verification]
    val user = auth.currentUser!!
    user.sendEmailVerification()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->

                if (task.isSuccessful) {
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext,
                            "Verification email sent to ${user.email} ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

                    Log.d("TAG", "sendEmailVerification")
                } else {
                    Log.d("TAG", "sendEmailVerification", task.exception)
                    Toast.makeText(baseContext,
                            "Failed to send verification email.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                // [END_EXCLUDE]
            }
    // [END send_email_verification]
}

fun createUSer(){
    database.child(USER_REF).child(uname).child("email").setValue(email)
    Log.d("CREATED","create user"+uname)
}


}
```

logcat

```
2020-11-11 17:57:45.290 28364-28364/com.bva_valai_pada E/zza: Problem 
retrieving SafetyNet Token: 7: 
2020-11-11 17:57:45.358 28364-28364/com.bva_valai_pada W/ActivityThread: 
handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5308a64
2020-11-11 17:57:45.873 28364-30352/com.bva_valai_pada E/FirebaseAuth: 
[GetAuthDomainTask] Error getting project config. Failed with {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "INVALID_CERT_HASH",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}
 400
2020-11-11 17:57:45.919 28364-28364/com.bva_valai_pada E/zza: Failed to get 
reCAPTCHA token - calling backend without app verification
2020-11-11 17:57:45.962 28364-28364/com.bva_valai_pada I/AssistStructure: 
Flattened final assist data: 4392 bytes, containing 1 windows, 13 views
2020-11-11 17:57:45.966 28364-28410/com.bva_valai_pada W/System: Ignoring 
header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
2020-11-11 17:57:46.611 28364-28410/com.bva_valai_pada E/FirebaseAuth: 
[SmsRetrieverHelper] SMS verification code request failed: unknown status 
code: 17093 null
2020-11-11 17:57:46.621 28364-28364/com.bva_valai_pada D/Exception: 
com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException: This request is missing a 
valid app identifier, meaning that neither SafetyNet checks nor reCAPTCHA 
checks succeeded. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.
```

Comment: Hey! Did you find any solution?

Comment: Yup I haven't added my SHA-1 key in firebase project and after adding it , my issue got solved

Comment: Why dont you add the steps to do so in here so its a one stop shop for the issue you faced years ago?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ah, it looks like you need to add a SHA-1 Certificate Hash to your application registration in the Firebase Console. I think you can find instructions to do that [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth)

Answer (score 7):

Your problem related to SHA1 and SHA256 keys. You have to add them to authenticate your certs.

- List item
- Goto

  Firebase Console of your project Authentication Project Setting (From
  Setting button near Project Overview) Add fingerprint Add SHA-1 and
  SHA-256 values of your keystore. You can get keystores from gradle
  like this.

> ./gradlew signingReport

Read this for more information: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#enable-app-verification

Comment: Thank You for your effort but I already got the answer and marked it correct

Answer (score 4):

> Step 1: Select a Project.
>
> Step 2 : Enable Android Device Verification
>
> Use below the link to Enable Android Device Verification.

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/library/androidcheck.googleapis.com

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to add fingerprint to your firebase project as below simple way

1. Goto your android studio and open Gradle tab from right corner.
2. Your app name > Run Configuration > ..[signingReport]> double click
   [image]
3. See your Terminal window from bottom and copy both SHA-1 and SHA-256 lines
4. Goto firebase.google.com > choose your project > project settings > general
5. Click on add fingerprint and paste your copied keys without including SHA-1 or SHA-256 name
6. Click add and re launch the app.

Comment: SHA-1 and SHA-256 both must be added in order to avoid the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was combination of the other answers:
.. Enable Android Device Verification per answer from @Tippu Fisal Sheriff
.. get SHA-1 and SHA-256 keys by running ./gradlew signingReport from    terminal, android folder per answer from @Sarwar Ahmed & @Malcolm Deck
.. on firebase website, going to project settings and 'add fingerprint" answer from from @Sarwar Ahmed